Constant stochastic process on the rationals
Let $X_r : r \in \mathbb{Q}$ be a stochastic process indexed by the set of all rationals.
We know that $X_r$ has the properties of uniform boundedness $|X_r| \le C, \forall r \in \mathbb{Q}$, pairwise independence and path continuity. Finally, assume $\mathbb{E}(X_r) =0 $.
Show that $X_r$ is the constant stochastic process, that is $X_r = 0$ for all $r \in \mathbb{Q}$
Going by a similar post: Independence of a Stochastic Process at Distinct Time, I can try to argue that for any sequence of rationals $r_n \rightarrow r$,
$X_r$ is constant almost surely. But I am not sure how to use the other condition of uniform boundedness?

Consider the random variables
$$
Z_n:={X_{-1/n}+X_{1/n}\over 2},\qquad n=1,2,\ldots.
$$
Clearly $|Z_n|\le C$ and (by path continuity) $\lim_n Z_n=X_0$. Therefore, by dominated convergence,
$$
\lim_n\Bbb E[Z_n^2]=\Bbb E[X_0^2].
$$
But also, by pairwise independence, because $\Bbb E[X_r]=0$,
$$
\Bbb E[Z_n^2] ={\Bbb E[X_{-1/n}^2]+\Bbb E[X_{1/n}^2]\over 4}.
$$
Again by dominated convergence and path continuity, the right side of this last display converges to $\Bbb E[X_0^2]/2$. Thus $\Bbb E[X_0^2]=\Bbb E[X_0^2]/2$, so $\Bbb E[X_0^2]=0$. Consequently, $\Bbb P[X_0=0]=1$. The same argument work for any other $r\in\Bbb Q$. Conclusion: $\Bbb P[X_r=0,\forall r\in\Bbb Q ]=1$.

I cannot fathom how you come up with these things. But let's not even worry about that. I do follow most of the steps but not the significance of the rationals.  Are they getting used in the fact that the random variable $Z_{n}$ could not be constructed otherwise ?  If so, why not ?

Any other countable dense set would serve as a substitute for $\Bbb Q$.
The rationals provide a way to construct $Z_n$, which approximates $X_0$. Taking $Z_n$ to be a linear combination of some of the $X_r$s is a way to use their independence, via the variance of $Z_n$, to conclude that the variance of $X_0$ must be $0$.

Hi John. So, since the reals are are not countable you needed the countable dense set to create $Z_{n}$.  Thanks so much. Still, you are minimizing the answer so I'll set you straight: You are REALLY talented.
